# A class array inside of a class - issues with dynamic arrays (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays

My homework is that I have to make a class (register) which contains 3 class arrays (birds, mammals, reptiles) which are in the animal class. Animal is the friend of Register. I will only show the birds part, to keep it simple.

The register class looks like:

```
class Register
{
    Bird* birds;
    unsigned int birdSize;
public:
    ...
}
```

The constructor of register:

```
Register::Register()
{
    this->birds = new Bird[0];
    this->birdSize = NULL;    
}
```

Now I have a function in register that adds one element to the birds array, the input is cin.

```
void Register::add()
{
 ...
        if (birdSize == 0)
        {
            birds = new Bird[0];
            Bird* temp = new Bird[0];
            temp[0].add();
            this->birds = temp;
            birdSize++;
        }
        else
        {
            Bird* temp = new Bird[birdSize+1];
            for (unsigned int i=0; i<=birdSize; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = this->birds[i];   
            }
            temp[birdSize+1].add();
            birds = new Bird[birdSize+1];
            birds = temp;
            birdSize++;
        }
```

temp[0].add() has the cin, it works properly. When I run the program, the user has to add 2 birds to the array. The problem occurs when reaching the part under 'else', so the second element of the array. The program surely reaches "temp[birdSize+1].add();" while running, then the "xyz.exe has stopped working" window pops up and it says in the details "  Fault Module Name:  StackHash_7e8e" so I'm sure something is wrong with the memory allocation, but the problem is that when I try to find the problematic line in debug mode, everything works fine.

Well, not everything. The program has a print() function, it prints out everything in Register. The second element of the array is the same as the first.

I have no clue what to do. I read many forum posts, read a cpp book, watched online tutorials, but I can't find the solution for this problem. Please help.

Comment: _Dynamic arrays_ in c++ are `std::vector<>` instances!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array index starts from `0`. So in `else` part you are writing

```
 Bird* temp = new Bird[birdSize+1]; // size =birdSize +1;
```

So  valid index range will be **0 ->  birdSize**, *not birdSize+1*.

The problem is

```
temp[birdSize+1].add();
```

you are using `birdSize+1`th index. It should be

```
temp[birdSize].add();
```

There are other bugs in your code:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<=birdSize; i++) // should be i<birdSize
{
  temp[i] = this->birds[i];   
}
```

There are other bad coding in your program:

```
Register::Register()
{
  this->birds = new Bird[0]; // should be this->birds=NULL
  this->birdSize = NULL;    // should be this->birdSize = 0
}
```

And obviously if your homework does not demand it, you should not use `array`s in this way. For variable size container, use `vector, list...`. `Array` is only when the **size is fixed**.

Comment: I see. I'll going to reprogram it using vectors, then I'll report in how it went. Thank you!

Comment: Of course, I wanted to do it but it has a 5 minute time limit or so. Thank you again.